# How does the compiler distinguish which module (library) is for testing only?

Tags: go

Suppose we have a project that uses some third party module (or library if you wish) that is used for testing only (ie. `github.com/stretchr/testify`). So we'll end up with `go.mod` file like this:

```
module example.org/myapp

go 1.13

require (
    ...
    github.com/go-resty/resty/v2 v2.2.0
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.7.4
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.3.0
    ...
)
```

As I can see there's no difference between a module that is used for production code and testify that is used for testing only (i.e. unlike in Java where we have dependency scopes like `test`, `compile` etc.) So how the golang compiler knows which dependency is not required for runtime and can be omitted in the compiled binary?

Comment: Libraries and modules are different things in Go. And modules, which you seem to be talking about, are not related to the compiler.

Comment: Libraries aren't specifically anything in Go, but as a general term could refer to modules, because modules meet the general definition of a "library" in software development; to say they're "different things in Go" implies that "library" is a term defined in the Go world, which it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. What is wrong about the question that it gets downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't just include everything in your `go.mod`; the compiler omits anything that isn't referenced from what it's building at the time. Correct test files are named `*_test.go` and are excluded by build constraints from non-test builds by default. Anything referenced only from those files will only be compiled into test builds.